# PHP code parsing error

Tags: php

I am writing php code.I keep on getting parse error i.e 
**Unexpected '?>'expecting function()**. I seem to be doing everything right.The problem is of a very basic nature,probably about matching  tags.I have gone through the code many times but couldn't find where the problem lies.Sorry for this trivial question.Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks.

```
<?php
class My_Widget extends WP_Widget { 

    function widget($args, $instance) {
        // output the content of widget
        extract($args);
        echo $before_width;
        echo $before_title.  'In this section'. $after_title;

        //run query if on the page
        if ( (is_page) ) {
            $ancestor  =  check_page_tree();
            // arguments for the children of ancestors.
            $args = array('child_of' => $ancestor,
                          'depth' => $instance['depth'],
                          'title_li' => '');
            // set value for get_pages to check if it's empty
            $list_pages = get_pages( $args );

            //check if $list_pages has value.
            if($list_pages) {

                // open a list with the ancestor page at the top
                ?>
                <ul class="page_tree">

                //list ancestor page
                <li class="ancestor">

                <a  href="<?php echo get_permalink($ancestor); ?>">
                <?php  echo get_the_title($ancestor);?></a>            
                </li>
                <?php 

                //use wp_list_pages to list subpages of ancestor or page
                wp_list_pages($args);

                ?>

                </ul>

                <?php
            } 

        }

    }
    ?>       <---------- here is the error unexpected ?> ------|       

    <?php

    function form($instance) {
        $defaults = array(
                          'depth' => '-1'
                          );
        $depth = $instance[ 'depth' ];
        // markup for form ?>


        <p> 
        <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('depth'); ?>"> 
        Depth of list: </label>
        <input  class = "widefat" type = "text" 
        id="<?php echo    $this->get_field_id('depth'); ?>" 
            name="<?php echo  $this->get_field_name('depth'); ?>" value="
        <?php echo esc_attr($depth) ; ?>" />
                                                                    </p>
        <?php
    }
    // end of class 
}
?>
```

Comment: What is is_page? Function? Variable? Constant?

Comment: Why have that closing tag at all? You just have a new line and then open PHP again? Try to indent your code properly and consistently and it' will be easier to see these errors.

Comment: @Barmar - Yes, I realized that, that's why I changed my comment. :)

Comment: Thanks a lot guys.Actually the problem was is_page(). It's a function in wordpress.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use `?>` outside functions in a class.  It can only be used where executable statements are allowed, since everything between `?>` and the next `<?php` is supposed to be echoed. Since you can't put `echo` statements in a class definition, you can't switch back to output mode with `?>`.

So just get rid of that `?>` and the following `<?php`.